# Remote shared printing with gsprint

Tags: c#, printing, ghostscript

First, let me explain the question.

With *gsprint* in the terminal, the document path is sent via command line, the document is converted to a bitmap and then sent to the specified printer. The printers in the list are the printers that **are installed** in the System and it doesn't allow you to specify a different printer in another computer.

I'm developing a web printing manager that, via *ajax*, calls the executable and sends the correct arguments to *gsprint*. Here comes the problem: The printers that I list in my application as available to print are printers that come from a C# method and brings the printers  of a remote computer in the same network. My printing list is not of the own server and I can send the files by using *RawPrinterHelper*, but I really² need to use *gsprint*. My C# method that brings the printers and filters the printers of a *PrintServer*:

```
public JsonResult GetPrinters()
{
  IList<string> printers = new List<string>();
  using(var printServer = new PrintServer(string.Format(@"\\{0}", "NITERE")))
  {
    foreach (var queue in printServer.GetPrintQuest()
      .Where(queue => queue.IsShared))
  }
  return Json(printers);
}
```

And this gives me a printer called `\\NITERE\Thermical Printer`.
When I send anything via *RawPrinterHelper*, it works really well.
When I send anything via *gsprint*, the bomb explodes. And *gsprint* just shame on my face:

```
> gsprint -grey -noquery -printer "\\NITERE\Thermical Printer"
> Copyright (C) 2003-2006, Ghostgum Software Pty Ltd.  All Rights Reserved.
2006-02-24 gsprint 1.9
Couldn't open Windows GDI printer driver
Requested printer: "\\NITERE\Thermical Printer" (Or whatever "\\\\NITERE\\Thermical Printer")
Available printers:
  "ZEBRA Labels Printer"
  "Capybaras are sexy"
  "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
  "Fax"
  "\\SERVER1\Default Printer"
  "\\SERVER1.local\Main"
```

Is there a way to allow *gsprint* to support shared printing this way?

Comment: I may be missing your point but.... Your list of available printers (which appears to include printers on a server called SERVER1) doesn't include a printer called 'Thermical Printer' on a server called NITERE. So either your list or available printers is incorrect, or there is no such printer available, so why should gsprint be able to print to it ?

Comment: Grr, couldn't edit the comment, timed out on me, so here's a new one. The list of printers there is the list of printers available to gsprint, and which includes at least 2 remote printers. Have you checked in your Windows Control Panel->Hardware and Sound->View devices and printers to see if the printer you are trying to reach is available there ? GSprint can only print to printers which are available to Windows.

Comment: This is the point. I can print programmatically by another tool. `\\NITERE\Thermical Printer` **isn't** mean to be listed. It is hidden, but I can print to it via `RawPrinterHelper`, in F# and C#.

Comment: I don't know how you can print to a hidden printer, but GSPrint only knows about the printers available to the OS, if the printer can't be seen by Windows then GSPrint can't print to it. Note that the bitmap created by Ghostscript is not sent directly to the printer, it is instead drawn to a compatible printer DeviceContext, and then the usual Windows printing system converts the contents of the DC to a form suitable for the printer. Thus it needs a suitable printer driver to be available and the printer to be available to the Windows Printing System.